# Add custom text to each product in cart - Magento 1.9X

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart

how can I attach a custom text to a product which will be added into the cart along with the product itself when adding it to cart and furthermore being passed through the whole order process like in order page in back office or on pdf invoices and so on??

Ex :

1. When customer is on my product page he has the opportunity to
   "customize" the product wih the help of a configuration wizard I
   have built with javascript/jquery.
2. List item At the end of this process customer can add customized
   product to cart which now has a custom price and a custom
   "ordertext" for me as the shop-owner to get all the customization
   information
3. When clicking on add-to-cart-button
   product is added to cart with new customprice and customtext

Please note that my custom text is not entered by customer. Instead it's gonna be generated by programmatically.

[image]

Comment: Mahesh whether you need like this? as shown in this screenshot  http://prntscr.com/faqa6h

Comment: Mahesh whether you need in the option in the 'custom options' section? as shown in this screenshot  http://prntscr.com/faqa6h

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating an event and observer using your extension and setting the custom price and text through observer.

Answer (score 0):

We have faced same requirements. So use the below mentioned coding.

**1)** use observer `<catalog_product_collection_load_after>` in your **`config.xml`** file.

```
<global>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_collection_load_after>
            <observers>
                <my_code_collection_load_after>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>My_Code_Model_Observer_Recurring</class>
                    <method>getProductValue</method>
                </my_code_collection_load_after>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_collection_load_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

**2)** Crate custom observer file "*root/app/code/community/My/Code/Model/Observer/Recurring.php*"

```
<?php

class My_Code_Model_Observer_Recurring
{

    public function getProductValue(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $items) {
            $additionalOptions = $items->getOptionByCode("additional_options");
            if (!empty($additionalOptions)) {
                $additionalValue = unserialize($additionalOptions->getValue());
                if (!isset($additionalValue['nn_subscription']) && empty($additionalValue['nn_subscription'])) {
                    $additionalValue['nn_subscription'] = array('label' => 'Custom Text Title', 'value' => 'Custom Text Value');
                    $serializeData = serialize($additionalValue);
                    $items->getOptionByCode("additional_options")->setValue($serializeData);
                }
            } else {
                $additionalValue['nn_subscription'] = array('label' => 'Custom Text Title', 'value' => 'Custom Text Value');
                $items->addOption(array(
                  "product_id" => $items->getProduct()->getId(),
                  'code' => "additional_options",
                  'value' => serialize($additionalValue)
            ));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Checkout cart Page:**

[image]
**Checkout review Page:**

[image]